# Vscode is not showing auto suggestions after one usage (shows up only one time)

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

I have a quite strange issue with my vscode which I can't figure out to fix. The auto suggestion is only showing up once and after that it's not showing any suggestions anymore. (Window size of it is fine)

So when I:

1. Open up vscode
2. Start to write something => It's working
3. When I do it again => It's not showing suggestions

Here a small clip:
https://i.imgur.com/OTrHwM0.mp4

Does anyone had this issue? Or has a tip how to fix it?